# THOR APT scanner -warning about a file I cannot find anymore

Tags: security, apt

I am using THOR Lite and I received the following error

> Jan 22 20:20:20 *hostname*/10.168.1.1 MODULE: Filescan MESSAGE:
> Possibly Dangerous file found SCORE: 75 FILE:
> C:\Sysmon\33D4E031D00EC0179FEE2558987DE54704A35597CB583B7F9335A95B063B560443779C0A7B576499F66520014A6A92BA3A43B7A17783C9B5C5FBF26D0E762CE41F09777396112B6B6508D4708E100F9CA644FDA1.exe
> EXT: .exe TYPE: EXE SIZE: 1700864 MD5:cb583b7f9335a95b063b560443779c0a
> SHA1:33d4e031d00ec0179fee2558987de54704a35597
> SHA256:7b576499f66520014a6a92ba3a43b7a17783c9b5c5fbf26d0e762ce41f097773
> FIRSTBYTES: 4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b8000000 / MZ CREATED: Wed
> Jul 19 21:50:38.887 2023 MODIFIED: Wed Jul 19 21:50:38.929 2023
> ACCESSED: Fri Jan 19 16:08:44.864 2024 PERMISSIONS: APPLICATION
> PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:R / APPLICATION PACKAGE
> AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:R /
> BUILTIN\Administrators:R / BUILTIN\Users:R / NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:R /
> NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:F OWNER: NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
> COMPANY: Microsoft Corporation DESC: CertUtil.exe LEGAL_COPYRIGHT: ©
> Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. PRODUCT: Microsoft®
> Windows® Operating System ORIGINAL_NAME: CertUtil.exe INTERNAL_NAME:
> CertUtil.exe IMPHASH: 96112b6b6508d4708e100f9ca644fda1 REASON_1: YARA
> rule APT_Cloaked_CERTUTIL / Detects a renamed certutil.exe utility
> that is often used to decode encoded payloads SUBSCORE_1: 75 REF_1:
> Internal Research SIGTYPE_1: internal SIGCLASS_1: YARA Rule

I connected to the machine and tried to look for the suspicious file "C:\Sysmon\33D4E031D00EC0179FEE2558987DE54704A35597CB583B7F9335A95B063B560443779C0A7B576499F66520014A6A92BA3A43B7A17783C9B5C5FBF26D0E762CE41F09777396112B6B6508D4708E100F9CA644FDA1.exe"
but I cannot find it, but I run THOR several times and the warning remains.

I tried to find sysmon file deletion events on the machine (sysmon is installed) without success. I looked for hidden folders and nothing either.

any other suggestion?